# Is there a way to have the console log tell me on what view i am on?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, console

I would like to know if the console log on xcode could tell by my command of course on what view/VC i am on.

I would like it to be very dynamic and not with coding inside the projec, and while playing the project on the device .
It is a very big project and i would like to play the app and ask the console on what view/vc i am on.
Hope i was clear
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

just override the NSLog method i'm using this :

```
#define NSLog(x, ...) NSLog(@"%s %d: " x, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

and you call : `NSLog(@"Your Message");`

the result is:`[YourVC viewWillAppear:] 269: Your Message`

Comment: Its not really the answer that i was looking for but its very usefull! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

So i found the answer, while on debug mode  i write to the console:
po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]

and here is a great link for debugging in xcode
http://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6